# Scrapy: Autopopulate extracted fields

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

To sum up my query in a few bullet points before expanding:

- Target website is a sports website with 100+ fields which I want to scrape.
- I would like to declare an empty class to fill with the field names and populate it with the relevant values.
- I am unclear how you alter the Items file for a scenario where you are not explicitly declaring your scraped items.

Now to get down to brass tacks.

I am looking to scrape from [a rugby database](http://omo.akamai.opta.net/?feed_type=ruf9&game_id=113013&user=OWV3&psw=trDd59TW). A snippet of the code is below:

```python
<TeamData Possession="0.50" Score="40" Side="Home" TeamRef="t1550" Territory="0">
  <Stat Type="restart_opp_player">0</Stat>
  <Stat Type="kick_oppn_collection">0</Stat>
  <Stat Type="kicks_from_hand">0</Stat>
  <Stat Type="penalty_conceded_killing_ruck">0</Stat>
  ...
```

This code continues on for around another 140 lines to make something that would be a pain to define each attribute explicitly.

Rather than extracting each attribute one by one, I would like to be able to define an empty class and then fill it with the various attributes. This is fairly easy to achieve within the shell.

```python
class RugbyItem(params):
 def __init__(self, params)
  selc.__dict__.update(params)

home_attribute_names = response.xpath('//TeamData[@Side="Home"]/Stat/@Type').extract()
home_attribute_stats = response.xpath('//TeamData[@Side="Home"]/Stat/text()').extract()
concat = {k: v for (k, v) in (zip(home_names, home_stats))}

home_data = RugbyItem(concat)
```

Based on the above, could someone help me in figuring out what way I should structure the Items file

```python
class RugbyItem(scrapy.Item):
 ??? = scrapy.Field()
```

and the Spider class.

```python
class MySpider(BaseSpider):
 name        = "rugbyspider"
 allowed_domains = ["opta.net"]
 start_urls  = ["http://omo.akamai.opta.net/?feed_type=ruf9&game_id=113013&user=OWV3&psw=trDd59TW"]

 def parse(self, response):
  home_attribute_names = response.xpath('//TeamData[@Side="Home"]/Stat/@Type').extract()
  home_attribute_stats = response.xpath('//TeamData[@Side="Home"]/Stat/text()').extract()
  concat = {k: v for (k, v) in (zip(home_names, home_stats))}
  home_data = RugbyItem(concat)
  yield home_data
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not obliged to yield a `scrapy.Item` instance, you can also yield a `dict`, which won't be bounded to the restrictions you want.